# Alternatives for php cURL - OpenId and Google, Facebook apis server side authentication

Tags: php, javascript, api, authentication, curl

Looks like most of the openid, facebook, google authentication apis and methods use PHP cURL for authenticating the external websites. My hosting service doesnt provide me with cURL enabled, so I had to do the authentication from client side java script. But it may not be secure. So can any one provide with open source php implementations which can be used for authenticating and using user data from google, facebook, linkedin, twitter etc.

Also can you please let me know where can I find example scripts for javascript/php (without need for curl/wrapper) authentication and user data access (like fetching user wall posts, user content, friends list, updates stream etc).

Note: I have seen external entities providing services for all kinds of open id authentications, but I want to do it myself with set of customizations for each (facebook, google, linkedin).

Comment: Depending on which other parts/extensions of PHP are enabled on your hoster, you might be able to use file_get_contents() (if URL-wrappers enabled) for GET methods.

Comment: I dont know if file_get_contents is enabled or not.. let me see... but other than that... is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn developer site has examples in php for retrieving information using the php pecl oauth extension here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide#toggleview:id=php

This guide will also work for twitter, and with some modification for Facebook.

Note that LinkedIn also has a JavaScript API which has the security abstracted for you if you decide to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents I would recommend if your host allows it http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

In addition there is also file_put_contents for posting http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

It may require some modification from your host those as from experience if cURL is disabled these are also